# My code is too complicated how should I make it simple?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm having trouble in making my Cypress code more streamlined.

```
cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(0).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true})
cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(1).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true})
cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(2).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true})
cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(3).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true})
```

How should I streamline this to not be a copy paste of itself?

Comment: `[0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(el => { cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(el).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true}); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cypress' `.each` command. [Documentation here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Syntax)

```
cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').each(($el, index) => {
  cy.wrap($el).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true})
});
```

If you needed to only take action on say the first 4 items, you could do a conditional based on the value of that `argument` parameter.

```
...
if (index < 4) {
  cy.wrap($el).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true})
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop

```
for (const el of [0, 1, 2, 3]) {
  cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(el).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true});
}
```

or array method:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(el => {
  cy.get('input[ng-change="$matterHourCtrl.forceRound()"]').eq(el).dblclick().type('{uparrow}', {multiple: true, force: true});
});
```